# How can I get my list component to render after the state has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, components, lifecycle

I have a calculator app which logs the ten most recent equations processed by any user in real time via firebase. It is supposed to automatically update the log any time someone from any device essentially hits the equal sign. It does this for the most part, except for the user actually pressing equals, in which case it is delayed by one equation. That user however can see others' submissions in real time.

I have two different variables in state. One is called logs which is an object that saves all of the logs from the database locally, and the other is called list which is an array updated via a function that processes logs and gets the ten most recent entries in order of time created. I have a component which maps through the list of ten to create `li` elements in my log component.

Here is my state and componentDidMount method:

```
this.state = {
      // input builds a string of user inputs
      input: '',
      // display is for the calculator screen
      display: '...',
      // stores all logs from db
      logs: {},
      // Make a list for 10 recent posts
      list: []
    }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
    document.addEventListener("keypress", this.handleKeyPress, true);
  }
```

Here are the functions that apply to this problem:

```
  // should fetch data (previous logs) for app on first render,
  // and also update logs live from user and other users
  fetchData = () => {
    // creating reference to root node of firebase db
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('/logs');
    // on "change" in db, pull all logs
    rootRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({
        logs: snapshot.val()
      });
      return this.tenMostRecentLogs(this.state.logs)
    }, function (errorObject) {
      return console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    })
  }

// take db object and update app state
  tenMostRecentLogs = obj => {
    // make array of all logs
    const logs = [
      Object.entries(obj)
    ];
    // create array of all logs sorted by timestamp
    const sortedLogs = logs[0].sort((a,b) => (a.timestamp < b.timestamp) ? 1 : -1)
    // create an array of ten most recent posted logs
    let tenLogsSorted = [];
    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
      let log = [];
      log.push(sortedLogs[i][1].eq);
      log.push(sortedLogs[i][1].id);
      tenLogsSorted.push(log)
    }
    this.setState({
      list: tenLogsSorted
    })
  }
```

And here is the component in question:

```
<div className='log'>
  <Log logs={this.state.list}/>
</div>
```

I've thought about forcing a re render of Log but i know thats frowned upon. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

App in question: https://calculatron-app.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Oh i see, so logs are always one calculation behind. (It doesnt get updated on the first calculation) is that right?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yeah exactly, for the user submitting it. But another user looking at the app on a different device will see that equation updated in real time. You can mess around it with at the link at the bottom to see what i mean if you want!

Comment: It also seems like if I leave it running for a bit, the error goes away...

Comment: Inside `fetchData`, are you intentionally passing `this.state.logs` into `tenMostRecentLogs` or did you mean to pass `snapshot.val()` instead? This is because at that time, `this.state.logs` will not reflect that you've passed `snapshot.val()` in the `setState` function.

Comment: @LadiAden actually no it wasn't intentional, and I think that fixes it!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

`this.setState()` is an async operation. So while calling `this.tenMostRecentLogs(this.state.logs)` it cannot get updated `logs` value immediately after calling `this.setState({})`. To get updated state immediately, you need to use `this.setState`'s callback function.

For example:
`this.setState({logs:value,},()=>{ this.tenMostRecentLogs(this.state.logs) })`

Also `this.tenMostRecentLogs()` is not returning any value as you've written `return this.tenMostRecentLogs(this.state.logs)`.

Remember, for a function return anything which is primitive or non-primitive data type value. It may be functions,objects,arrays or number,string,etc...

Comment: My pleasure to provide an assit to you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this here as a cleaner way of doing what you want to do.

```
fetchData = () => {
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('/logs');

  rootRef.on('value',
    snapshot => this.tenMostRecentLogs(snapshot.val()),
    errorObject => console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code)
  );
}

tenMostRecentLogs = obj => {
  // the rest of your operation...

  this.setState({
    list: tenLogsSorted,
    logs: obj
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.tenMostRecentLogs(snapshot.val())
```

inside of fetchData() instead of

```
return this.tenMostRecentLogs(this.state.logs)
```

thank you @LadiAden!!!!